# Convert number bases

Tags: code-golf, math

What your function must do:
be as short (in bytes) as possible
take 3 inputs that are strings: number , fromdigits, todigits
assume no digit is repeated in fromdigits or todigits
assume fromdigit and todigit contain only alphanumeric characters
assume number is a natural number
output (a string): number converted to frombase
examples:
`convert("ff","0123456789abcdef","0123456789")="255"`
`convert("ee","fecdba9876543210","9876543210")="82"`
example code (283 bytes, in python 3.4.1):

```
def convert(number,fromdigits,todigits):
    x=0
    for digit in str(number): 
        x = x*len(fromdigits)+fromdigits.index(digit)
    res=""
    while x>0:
        digit = x % len(todigits)
        res = todigits[digit] + res
        x //= len(todigits)
    return res
```

Comment: For a fastest code challenge, you need to say how you're going to measure the speed of the code. What inputs will be used? On what system will it be measured?

Comment: be as short (in bytes) as possible

Comment: Then the tag you're looking for is [tag:code-golf].

Comment: Almost there! You should specify the format of the input and output. You say "program" but define a function. The default is to allow both. Also, is there a limit to the characters that may be used to represent digits?

Comment: Your code handles negative values. Is that a requirement? That's worth clarifying, as well as the fact the numbers are presumably integers rather than floats. Also, it seems clear that the output is a string, but that's worth saying explicitly.

Comment: The output of the `convert("ff","0123456789abcdef","0123456789")` call should be `255` instead of `256`

Comment: How to convert '0'? The example code returns '', is it correct?

Comment: i assume so, since zero=nothing

Answer (score 1):

## Python - 101

To get started I basically golfed your example code...

```
def c(n,f,t,x=0,r=""):
 for d in n:x=x*len(f)+f.index(d)
 while x:l=len(t);r=t[x%l]+r;x//=l
 return r
```

Answer (score 1):

### APL (40)

Can't beat CJam anymore it seems.

```
{⎕IO←0⋄⍵⍵[N⊤⍨(⌊1+Z⍟N←(⍴⍺⍺)⊥⍺⍺⍳⍵)/Z←⍴⍵⍵]}
```

This takes the *fromdigits* and *todigits* values as its `⍺⍺` and `⍵⍵` arguments, and the number itself as the `⍵` argument, i.e.:

```
      ('0123456789abcdef'{⎕IO←0⋄⍵⍵[N⊤⍨(⌊1+Z⍟N←(⍴⍺⍺)⊥⍺⍺⍳⍵)/Z←⍴⍵⍵]}'0123456789')'ff'
255
      ⍝ for ease of reading
      convert ← {⎕IO←0⋄⍵⍵[N⊤⍨(⌊1+Z⍟N←(⍴⍺⍺)⊥⍺⍺⍳⍵)/Z←⍴⍵⍵]}
      ('0123456789abcdef' convert '0123456789') 'ff'
255
      ('fedcba9876543210' convert '9876543210') 'ee'
82
      ('0123456789' convert '01') '254'
11111110
```

Explanation:

- `⎕IO←0`: set the index origin to `0`. (APL arrays start at `1` by default and we don't need that here.)
- `Z←⍴⍵⍵`: store the length of `⍵⍵` in `Z`. This is the base to convert to.
- `N←(⍴⍺⍺)⊥⍺⍺⍳⍵`: look up the index (`⍳`) in `⍺⍺` of each value in `⍵`. These are the digits in the base to convert from. Then decode (`⊥`) this from the input base, which is the length of `⍺⍺`. Store this value in `N`.
- `⌊1+Z⍟N`: find the amount of digits required to represent value `N` in base `Z`.
- `(`...`)/Z`: replicate `Z` that many times.
- `N⊤⍨`: encode `N` into the output base.
- `⍵⍵[`...`]`: for each digit of that, find the corresponding character in `⍵⍵`.

Comment: Why do you use 2 character variable names, plus, since those are unicodes, they are 4 bytes each

Comment: @Optimizer: the APL charset [fits in a byte just fine](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/resources/systems_i_software_globalization_pdf_cp00907z.pdf), and the 2-character variable names are just what APL calls them. `⍺` and `⍵` are function arguments, and `⍺⍺` and `⍵⍵` are the operator arguments. What this code is in fact doing is defining a 'convert' operator that takes two base strings on `⍺⍺` and `⍵⍵`, which then gives a function that takes the number to be converted on `⍵`.

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, 20 bytes

```
rr:Ff#F,bAbsr:Tf#T,b
```

Input is like:

```
ee fecdba9876543210 9876543210
```

Output:

```
82
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)